# How do I exchange multiple fields in a link?

Tags: javascript, html

I can easily replace one input field with a word in a link, but how do I do it if i need to exchange multiple fields?

I tried out everything I know, but I couldn't find a solution. This is the code for one word exchange that I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sdc_go(l){location.href=l.replace(/TEST/ , escape(document.forms[0].elements[0].value));}
</script>

<div>
  <p align="center">
    <input type="text" test="l" value="" style="width:100px;font-size:16px">
  <p align="center">
    <input name="button23" type="button" class="inp1" onClick="sdc_go('https://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=TEST&oq=TEST&gs_l=hp.3..35i39j0i20j0l2.3900.4643.0.6333.4.4.0.0.0.0.401.1543.3-2j2.4.0.cappswebkhl..0.0...1.1.12.psy-ab.mJYg6DhkQu0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.eWU&fp=5d2a0caa618f44e0&biw=1464&bih=815')" value="Google">
</div>
```

Can anyone help me understand how I can adapt this to get multiple entry fields and words exchanged?

Answer (score 0):

Try `/TEST/g`

It's a global replace of all occurances of the pattern

Comment: thank you, but i need multiple fields with multiple exchanges. i'm not looking to exchange all words. let me try to explain it a bit more precise................................................................................................................

name: ___ / prename: ___ / link: google.com/name_prename ....................................................................
result: name: yuriy / prename: galanter / link: google.com/galanter_yuriy ........................................................
hope this helps